# vim how to page down/up in another window

Tags: key-bindings

**Context:**

There are 2 and only windows in vim. I want when I press <kbd>F2</kbd>, cursor remain in the same window, the other window behave like <kbd>PgDn</kbd>pressed.

How to achieve that behavior?

**P.S.**

motivation: used in a preview mode, one window containing a `dirvish` buffer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following mapping should to the trick

```
nnoremap <F2> <C-w>p<C-f><C-w>p
```

It remaps `F2` to change to the previously accessed window ([`:h CTRL-W_p`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#CTRL-W_CTRL-P)), scroll down ([`:h CTRL-F`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/scroll.txt.html#CTRL-F)) and come back to the previous window.